# How to customize the background color of UITableView section in iOS 7 with methods like colorWithHexString

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

In iOS7 the UITableView section header background color white in default. But how

can i customize section background with hexadecimal color codes in iOS7 (My table view is not

a Grouped table view.). Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code

```
  -(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
 {
      [self.viewSection setBackgroundColor: [self colorWithHexString:@"FFFFFF"]];

      return viewSection;
}





-(UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hex  
{  
    NSString *cString = [[hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];  

// String should be 6 or 8 characters  
  if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];  

// strip 0X if it appears  
if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];  

if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];  

// Separate into r, g, b substrings  
NSRange range;  
range.location = 0;  
range.length = 2;  
NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];  

range.location = 2;  
NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];  

range.location = 4;  
NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];  

// Scan values  
unsigned int r, g, b;  
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];  
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];  
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];  

return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)  
                       green:((float) g / 255.0f)  
                        blue:((float) b / 255.0f)  
                       alpha:1.0f];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For UIColor with hex values easy to use categories, like this: https://github.com/avdyushin/UIColor-colorWithHex

`UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHex:0xbacd12];`

For custom section header to need to create new view with background color and return it in `-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which support alpha colours like #44FF0000

```
+ (UIColor *) colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
NSString *cleanString = [hexString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
if([cleanString length] == 3) {
    NSString *red = [cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    NSString *green = [cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
    NSString *blue = [cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)];
    cleanString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ff%1$@%1$@%2$@%2$@%3$@%3$@", red, green, blue];
}else if([cleanString length] == 6) {
    cleanString = [@"ff" stringByAppendingString:cleanString];
}else{
    //do nothing
}

NSLog(@"%@", cleanString);

unsigned int rgba;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:cleanString] scanHexInt:&rgba];

CGFloat alpha = ((rgba & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0f;
CGFloat red = ((rgba & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0f;
CGFloat green = ((rgba & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255.0f;
CGFloat blue = (rgba & 0x000000FF) / 255.0f;

return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
```

}

You can get full project from my blog post [hrupin.com](http://www.hrupin.com/2014/10/how-to-use-hexadecimal-colours-in-ios)